# Can I %cd to the value of an environment variable directly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using a group of interesting, but not very well written notebooks from a github repository, which occasionally assume a particular path for loading resources.

I want to simply change the current working directory to a path which is in an environment variable.

Yes I can load the os python module. Yes I can use several lines of code to unpack the list returned by `!echo $PROJECT_DIRECTORY`, and then use `%cd`.  I don't want to exit jupyter and use a command-line argument when I stumble upon this kind of problem. I want the least complex, most readable cell to do the trick.

Is there some syntax that lets me `%cd` directly to the value of an environment variable?  Looking something like:

```
%cd ${PROJECT_DIR}
```

P.S. It seems that `%env` can't use the value of an environment variable, only display it. Am I wrong?

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
%env PROJECT_DIR
%cd {_}
```